# Зачем нужна команда git fsck

Tags: git

Не могу понять зачем нужна команда `git fsck`

В гугле нашел только [эту](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21151945/what-does-git-fsck-stand-for)  ссылку и [эту](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck). Прочитал, но все равно ничего не понял.

Есть тут кто использовал эту команду в реальной жизни. Можно развернутые примеры пожалуйста? Как и где использовать. Если есть ссылку буду рад также прочитать то что я сам не смог найти.

Comment: Еще находится https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/Git-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85

Comment: @RomanKonoval Отлично! Прочитаю, спасибо!

Comment: Она не нужна. Если вам все-таки приходится ее использовать, то это означает, что что-то пошло не так.

Comment: @user7860670 если вы не знаете как работает это команда это не означает что она не нужна либо используется  там где что-то пошло не так.

Comment: ¿Почему вы решили, что я не знаю, как работает эта команда?

Comment: Я использовал `git fsck --lost-found` когда потерял зависимости. Типа как я понял, что просто проверяем целостность и если где то утрачена зависимость, то восстанавливаем в директорию где то в .git. Полезно было когда чистил кэш.